# Getting Started: Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've started with the Google Developer's tutorial on how to build a Chrome Extension.  (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted) I followed the directions, but popup window will not generate any photos.  (Description, flavicon, etc all load fine.)

At first I thought the Flickr API key was invalid, but even updating the key to a valid key doesn't do anything.  I also tried disabling all my other extensions to make certain that it wasn't conflicting, as well as opening it in new window.  I've also run the code through JSFiddle to see if there was something invalid.

Can someone fill me in on what's missing to make this work?  (From what I can tell, it's an authentication token issue or lack thereof.)

EDIT:

This is the popup.js file.  I did not alter the code.  This is the original file downloaded from the site.  I was avoiding posting the entire file because it's rather long.  (I disabled all my extensions and tried to run the practice extension given, and it's still giving me an empty popup box.)

```
// Copyright (c) 2012 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

/**
* Global variable containing the query we'd like to pass to Flickr. In this
* case, kittens!
*
* @type {string}
*/
var QUERY = 'kittens';

var kittenGenerator = {
/**
* Flickr URL that will give us lots and lots of whatever we're looking for.
*
* See http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html for
* details about the construction of this URL.
*
* @type {string}
* @private
*/
searchOnFlickr_: 'https://secure.flickr.com/services/rest/?' +
  'method=flickr.photos.search&' +
  'api_key=42cd5ea89847bd3b8f211ddbb7a6b789' +
  'text=' + encodeURIComponent(QUERY) + '&' +
  'safe_search=1&' +
  'content_type=1&' +
  'sort=interestingness-desc&' +
  'per_page=20',

 /**
 * Sends an XHR GET request to grab photos of lots and lots of kittens. The
 * XHR's 'onload' event is hooks up to the 'showPhotos_' method.
*
* @public
*/
requestKittens: function() {
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", this.searchOnFlickr_, true);
req.onload = this.showPhotos_.bind(this);
req.send(null);
 },

/**
* Handle the 'onload' event of our kitten XHR request, generated in
* 'requestKittens', by generating 'img' elements, and stuffing them into
* the document for display.
*
* @param {ProgressEvent} e The XHR ProgressEvent.
* @private
*/
showPhotos_: function (e) {
var kittens = e.target.responseXML.querySelectorAll('photo');
for (var i = 0; i < kittens.length; i++) {
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = this.constructKittenURL_(kittens[i]);
  img.setAttribute('alt', kittens[i].getAttribute('title'));
  document.body.appendChild(img);
 }
 },

/**
 * Given a photo, construct a URL using the method outlined at
 * http://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.urlKittenl
 *
 * @param {DOMElement} A kitten.
 * @return {string} The kitten's URL.
 * @private
 */
constructKittenURL_: function (photo) {
return "http://farm" + photo.getAttribute("farm") +
    ".static.flickr.com/" + photo.getAttribute("server") +
    "/" + photo.getAttribute("id") +
    "_" + photo.getAttribute("secret") +
    "_s.jpg";
 }
};

// Run our kitten generation script as soon as the document's DOM is ready.
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
kittenGenerator.requestKittens();
});
```

Comment: If you show us something we can take a look and say what missing, however you're not showing us anything at the moment.

Comment: have you made any changs to the source code. Download the source code,  start the developerss mode, click on load unpacked extension. It should work.

Comment: Well, I just replaced `kittenGenerator.requestKittens();` with `var div = document.createElement('div');
 div.innerText = 'someText';
 document.body.appendChild(div);` - as a result, the box contains "someText". I guess that means that the extension 'functions' okay. I couldn't see a date on the extension page when I looked yesterday, but now see inside `popup.js` that it has a copyright notice from **2012**, so I guess that something in the Flickr side of things has changed. Just like you, I've no idea what, but a search of Flickr's docs should hopefully reveal the problem.

Comment: I got a new api key from flickr, patched that in and it started working.

Answer (score 1):

I think i might found the answer, this is the message from flickr.com:

> Parameterless searches have been disabled. Please use flickr.photos.getRecent instead.

just use flickr.photos.getRecent instead, and delete the unnecessary parameter is ok.